# Change contrast in PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I don't know, it may be off topic question. I am using Darcula theme in PhpStorm. I need to add more contrast (darker background, brighter text) in PhpStorm.

I googled a lot but I could not find appropriate answer for changing that. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: *" I need to add more contrast (darker background, brighter text)"* For what elements? In other words -- where?

Comment: It's clear in the question, I need to make darker background and brighter text than the theme originally uses.

Comment: For your information (to make your "it's clear in the question" not so *clear*) -- there are Editor color schema as well as GUI Theme called Darcula. And I need to know which of them you want to change. So -- is it about colors of Editor area .. or other parts (e.g. menu, tool windows etc)? You are using word "theme" but inside IDE this word used in when describing GUI Theme ... while you may be referring to editor color schema.

Comment: If you want to make changes to Editor color schema .. then `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General | Text --> Default text` -- you can change colors for `Foreground` for text and `Background` for background. **Please note** that individual languages *may* override background colors in some cases. For example -- PHP: since pure php file starts with `<?php` tag .. and that tag can have separate background color (`PHP | PHP Code | Background`) you may face situation when .php files have different background color -- the above mentioned style is the one to change

Comment: If you want to change colors of GUI Theme (tool windows/dialogs/active tab background/etc) then it cannot be done -- GUI Theme  (a.k.a. Look&Feel) do not offer customisation of any kind.

Answer (score 4):

While this post is dated, searching for an answer to what I believe to be a similar problem brought me here. In my case I could not easily read the line numbers on my display. The contrast was too weak.

I will answer this with the steps I took as it may help others who stumble onto this:

To configure it I opened Settings/Preferences dialog, and under the Editor node, clicked Colors & Fonts and then the General section. In this section I was able to find Code => Line number (in my case). In the case of the OP the section will be Text => Default text.

There you can change the colors and contrast directly to your liking.[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Dom: Thx for your answer. It helped me to enhance the contrast.

In the IntelliJ IDEA 2018 Version you can find this under:

File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General

From there choose:
Text > Default Text